# How to get rid of youtube bottom bar & title?

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox

Is there a way to get rid of the bottom status bar on youtube when it plays through fancybox?
I tried to append "controls = "0"" but the bottom bar stayed for the duration of the clip.

Also is there a way for the "X" button on the top corner to fade out after a bit? or at least move the button a little away from the video box?

[image]

HTML:

```
<a class="fancybox-media" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqRPrGeBVL0&autoplay=1"    >Vimeo</a>
```

Javascript:

```
$("a.fancybox-media").click(function() {
                 $.fancybox({
                  'padding'             : 0,
                  'autoScale'   : false,
                  'transitionIn'        : 'none',
                  'transitionOut'       : 'none',
                  'title'               : this.title,
                  'width'               : 680,
                  'height'              : 495,
                  'autoPlay'            :'true',
                  'href'                : this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
                  'type'                : 'swf',    // <--add a comma here
                  'swf'                 : {'allowfullscreen':'true'} // <-- flashvars here
                  });
                 return false;

});
```

Comment: can you put in a link to the site?

Comment: we are currently building the landing page for our mobile app, it should go live in about 5 days, but we don't have it up on our servers yet.  if noone can answer by then, I'll put up the link for you

Comment: `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqRPrGeBVL0&autoplay=1&controls=0` - that works for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `autohide=1` option to your command line (in your `href`) like:

```
<a class="fancybox-media" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqRPrGeBVL0&autoplay=1&autohide=1" >Vimeo</a>
```

For the "`close`" button, you could add this optioin to your script:

```
'onComplete': function(){
 $("#fancybox-close").css({"opacity":"0.5"});
}
```

adjust the opacity value as you wish

Comment: but the "close" button script doesnt work. when i add that code, the link just goes straight to youtube.com, instead of opening a box

Comment: just make sure you are not missing a comma to separate the options (if you added the script after the `'swf':{}` option, add a comma after the closing bracket of that option `'swf':{},//<--comma` the same way you separate all of them)